# redmine email configuration with smtp

Tags: smtp, redmine, redmine-plugins

I installed Redmine 2.6.1.1 using Bitnami on Win 7, but couldn't figure out why redmine cannot send any email. I edited the configuration.yml file under \redmine-2.6.1-1\apps\redmine\htdocs\config and tried to send a test mail via both Gmail and our own e-mail server, but it didn't work.

My configuration.yml file is just like below:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: smtp.gmail.com
      port: 587
      domain: smtp.gmail.com
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "someusername@gmail.com"
      password: "somepassword"
```

In this configuration the error is:

> an error occurred while sending mail (a socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. - connect (2))

If I change the address and domain values with IP addresses then the error becomes:

> an error occurred while sending mail (Permission denied - connect(2))

If I try to configure it with the values of our own mail server, then I still get the second error (permission denied).

I tried it in another PC and it worked. However, the same configuration in the old PC, it does not work. 2 PCs are in the same network and the only difference between 2 installations is that I did not configure mail settings during the Bitnami installtion in the old machine. After the installation was completed, I modified configuration.yml. However, in the new PC, I configured it during the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem finally. The reason is McAfee security. When I disable McAfee's "Access Protection" task, it worked without any problem.